# Trying to display tables in the one view in my MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I creating a repository in a MVC application which displays data in a SQL database.

In my Application view, when creating a new record i want to display my servers in my Server DB.

My Application details are in my application view and my server details are in my Server view.

Below is what i want to be in my App View, however due to this being in the App Model I don’t think this is possible. Does anyone know how to have 2 different databases in the one view?

```
  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Servers, "Servrs", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Servers", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Servers, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you elaborate more? Are you using EF, or ADO .Net? You view should depend only on model and not linked to anything. Your server side code should decide to send relevant information to your model. Again, if you add more clarification, then SO users will be able to help more.

Comment: Hi, I am using an EF application. I want to display a drop down within my App view of all my Servers.

Comment: So? Put that information in your view model so that your view can render the appropriate UI for it. The view model that you pass to your view should contain all the appropriate information that the view needs to render itself.